# Check if an array is a column of a large matrix—Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matrix

My code needs to check if a randomly generated array is a column of a large matrix in each iteration. The code goes like this:

```
large_matrix=np.zeros((arr_size,loop_size))
flag = 0
while flag < loop_size:
    arr = arr_generator(arr_size)
    dist = np.sum(large_matrix-arr,axis=0)
    if 0 in dist:
        continue
    else:
        large_matrix[:,flag] = arr
        flag += 1
```

The arr is **binary**, and because the **large _matrix takes a lot of memory**. This piece of code is pretty slow. Is there a more efficient method to deal with this problem in numpy?

Comment: There's many ways you could do this, one way would be to sum `large_matrix` and store that outside the loop, and then check if the `sum(arr)` is in that vector of sums.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, `sum(large_matrix)` is changing as the loop goes on, plus, `arr` is randomly generated which means the permutation of the two kinds of elements of the array matters. So I can not differentiate different `arr` by just using `sum(arr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this question, using the uniqueness of the product of prime numbers might be a good way to solve the problem. To use the prime numbers, we need:

1. an array used to store the prime numbers
2. an array generator which can yield the information of the index of different kinds of elements (since the array, in this case, is binary, we only need to know the index of one type of element in the array.)
3. To fix the overflow problem caused by the product of prime numbers, we need to calculate the logarithm of the product:

The code is rewritten as follows:

```
PRIME_NUMBER=np.array([2,3,5,7,11,13,17,23,29,31....], dtype='float')
flag = 0
loop_size = 100000
arr_size = 8
config = np.zeros(loop_size)
large_matrix=np.zeros((arr_size,loop_size))

while flag < loop_size:
    arr, idx = arr_generator(arr_size)
    prod = np.round(np.log10(np.prod(PRIME_NUMBER[idx])), 3)
    if prod in config:
        continue
    else:
        large_matrix[:,flag] = arr
        flag += 1
```